# Get member object from mentioned user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a discord bot written in python, one of the commands pulls up stats for a user that you ping with `>stats @user`. I want the bot to repeat the mentioned user's name without pinging them but can't figure out how.

```py
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx,a):
  b = str(a)
  b = b.replace("<","")
  b = b.replace(">","")
  b = b.replace("!","")
  user = b.replace("@","")
  path = 'users/'+user+'.txt'
  file = open(path,'r')
  lines = file.read()
  lines2 = lines.splitlines()
  file.close()
  await ctx.channel.send('Stats for '+a+'\nExp: '+lines2[0]+'\nMessages Sent: '+lines2[1])
```

Currently, the bot **does say the user's name**, but pings them, which results in the user being pinged twice. Once during initiation of the command and once it is carried out. I looked into other questions but couldn't find an answer that worked for me.

Comment: ... 'Stats for '+a+'\nExp: '.... maybe use ... 'Stats for '+user+'\nExp: ' ....

Comment: That ends up printing out the user's ID, which is just a long string of numbers
the id is useful for other parts of the code, but its near impossible to tell who an ID belongs to

Comment: if its pinging them and you want to only mention the users name. If this is an example of a users name, you could `user = "@testing#2402"` and then `username = user.split('@')[1].split('#')[0]`

Comment: You could also do `idx = user.find('#')` and then `username = user[1:idx]`

Comment: @SnitzFoam it sounds like you're asking two completely different questions, the post title and the question in the description doesn't match, which one is it?

Comment: sorry, from what ive seen i need a member object to use member.name, which would give me the display name of that user, but i dont know how to turn that a into a member object of the user it represents

Answer (score 1):

I ignored the code where you read from file and focused only on parts you need to change:

```py
@client.command()
async def stats(ctx, a : discord.Member): #here you identify "a" as discord.Member object
  await ctx.channel.send(f'Stats for {a.name}') #then you can get name
```

Check out [discord.Member in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?r#discord.Member) to learn what can you do with it.